# Angular type error: getBBox() is not a function on ElementRef

Tags: css, angular, bounding-box, elementref

I am calling this.container.nativeElement.getBBox() in ngAfterViewInit — as you can see in the screenshot, this is causing an error and getBBox() is supposedly not a function. The strange thing is that getBoundingClientRect() works just fine on the element. What could the issue be here?

[Screenshot of error message in dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk4Zn.png)

Comment: share the code. this information is not enough to provide any correct reason.

Comment: The code is one line, hahah. this.container.nativeElement.getBBox(). It's the first line in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: He means you need to share the context of the code. How do we know what this.container is and how it is declared... You need more than one line to figure out the issue.